# ParseError in solidity code

Tags: solidity, contract-development, compiler

This is the error i get.

> ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or
>   contract/interface/library definition.

This is my Solidity contract code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6

contract Inbox
{

    string public message;

    function Inbox(string intialMessage){
        message = intialMessage;
    }
    function setMessage(string newMessage){
        message = newMessage;
    }

}
```

I cannot figure out why this parse error is occurring. I tried changing the solidity version as well. Didn't work out.

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code, it's hard for others to test. even the error message :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed the semicolon in the first line. It should be,

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;
```

I tried the code in Remix IDE and it compiles after the above correction.

Answer (score 3):

`pragma` keyword in solidity has a `;` at the end of the line. you've forgotten it. It should be like,

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;
```

Answer (score 3):

As other answers also have pointed, You just have missed the `;` at the end of the very first line.